# Waiting for all setStates to finish updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my parent component, I render multiple child components as well as a save button. When the save button is clicked, the following method is called:

```
 submit() { 
   validateControls();
 }

 validateControls() {
    for (var key in this.refs) {
        let ref = this.refs[key];
        ref.setState({ force: true });
    }
}
```

The validateControls method ideally should loop through all refs, and call the setState for each component. Setting this state, will force the component to re-render and ofcourse validate itself as the validation is done within the component.

The child component will then have a class name "invalid" if it is invalid, so in the end after validateControls() is called, the submit method will check if a class with "invalid" as its name exist, if it does then the page isn't valid.

However, the issue im having is that the for loop isn't waiting for the setState to complete, therefore when the validateControls() method is finished, none of the controls have "invalid" as there class name.

Is there a way to wait for setState to finish and then move onto the next loop within the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a function as the last argument of `setState`, that function will be called after the state has been set.

Here is an example:

```
async submit() { 
  await validateControls();
}

async changeRefState(ref) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        ref.setState({ force: true }, resolve);
    })
}

async validateControls() {
    for (var key in this.refs) {
        await this.changeRefState(this.refs[key])
    }
}
```

In any case, using references to interact with child components is not the best approach, is better to do that through props.